# In df1_Drop[ID_posin1] <- df2_Pick[ID_posin2]number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Tags: r

Below is the code which was working fine and today suddenly came up with warning

The code is used in the below line

I am unable to find why is the warning showing and the output is also not correct.

```
Cost_match<-match_cost(SingleValueDistribute = F,df1_ID = Net_Rev$`Man.ID`, 
                       df2_ID = Production_cost$Man.ID, 
                       df2_Pick = Production_cost$Man.Revenue, 
                       df1_Drop = Net_Rev$`Man.Revenue`, 
                       df1_Dist_by = Net_Rev$Revenue,dist = T,weighted = T)
```

> Warning message: In df1_Drop[ID_posin1] <- df2_Pick[ID_posin2] :
>   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

```
match_cost<-function(SingleValueDistribute=F, df1_ID,df2_ID,df2_Pick,df1_Drop,df1_Dist_by,weighted=F,dist=F){
  # SingleValueDistribute allows to distribute a single value across many rows
  # IDs not needed in this case

  if(SingleValueDistribute==T) {
    sum<-sum(df1_Dist_by)
    perc<-df1_Dist_by/sum
    cost<-df2_Pick
    df1_Drop<-perc*cost 
    reps<-NULL
    print(" Singular Value Distributed")
  }else{                                                  
    df<-data.frame(table(df1_ID))
    df<-df[which(df$df1_ID %in% df2_ID),]
    reps<-as.character(unique(df$df1_ID[which(df$Freq>1)])) 

    if (length(reps)>0 & dist==F) {
      print("Multiple IDs; Values not Distributed")
    } else if(length(reps)>0 & dist==T & weighted==T){ 


      for(i in df2_ID){ #Loop to distribued by df1_Dist_by
        rows<-which(df1_ID==i)
        sum<-sum(df1_Dist_by[rows])
        cost<-df2_Pick[which(df2_ID==i)]
        if(sum==0){
          df1_Drop[rows][1]<-cost
        }else{
          perc<-df1_Dist_by[rows]/sum
          df1_Drop[rows]<-perc*cost
        }
      } 
      print("Multiple IDs; Value Weighted and Distributed")
    }else{
      # Direct matching     
      unique_ID<-unique(df2_ID) #Get unique IDs

      #Find positions of unique IDs the two data sets
      ID_posin1<-   match(x = unique_ID, table = df1_ID, nomatch = 0) # Find position of unique Ids
      ID_posin2<-   match(x = unique_ID, table = df2_ID, nomatch = 0) # Find position of unique Ids

      # Find corresponding cost positions

      df1_Drop[ID_posin1]<-df2_Pick[ID_posin2]                
      if(length(reps)>0) print("Multiple IDs; Values singularly Distributed") else 
        print("Singular IDs; Values Distributed")
    }
  }
  return(list(df1_Drop=df1_Drop,rep_ID=reps))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a data discrepancy between your two data sources which you did not see in your initial dataset. It looks like you are assuming that all df1 IDs are in df2 and *vice versa*.

```
unique_ID <- 100:101
df1_Drop <- 1:3
df2_Pick <- 4:6
# Find positions of unique IDs the two data sets
# Find position of unique Ids
ID_posin1 <- match(x = unique_ID, table = 101:103, nomatch = 0) 
ID_posin1
# [1] 0 1

# Find position of unique Ids
ID_posin2 <- match(x = unique_ID, table = 100:103, nomatch = 0) 
ID_posin2
# [1] 1 2

df1_Drop[ID_posin1] <- df2_Pick[ID_posin2]
# Warning message:
# In df1_Drop[ID_posin1] <- df2_Pick[ID_posin2] :
#   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

df1_Drop
# [1] 4 2 3
```

Make a habit of testing all assumptions you make at the start of a function and you will be less likely to come across surprises! For example:

```
# check inputs
if (!all(df1_ID %in% df2_ID)) { stop("not all df1_ID are in df2_ID") }
if (!all(df2_ID %in% df1_ID)) { stop("not all df2_ID are in df1_ID") }
```

EDIT: I think the following block does not have the behaviour that you want:

```
  # Direct matching     
  unique_ID<-unique(df2_ID) #Get unique IDs

  #Find positions of unique IDs the two data sets
  # Find position of unique Ids
  ID_posin1<-   match(x = unique_ID, table = df1_ID, nomatch = 0) 
  # Find position of unique Ids
  ID_posin2<-   match(x = unique_ID, table = df2_ID, nomatch = 0) 

  # Find corresponding cost positions

  df1_Drop[ID_posin1]<-df2_Pick[ID_posin2]
```

You are trying to update records corresponding to IDs, but it is quite risky to do this unless you are certain that each record for each ID is in the same place. I would not make this assumption for a dataset, but would instead allocate data by ID in df1. If you are expecting multiple Drop per ID, this should be made more sophisticated to handle miss-matches between number of records in df1 and df2.

```
df1_ID <- 100:101
df2_ID <- 101:102
df1_Drop <- 1:2
df2_Pick <- 4:5
unique_ID1 <- unique(df1_ID)

for (id in seq_along(unique_ID1)) {
    # how many unique Pick records are there for each ID in df2?
    nrec <- length(unique(df2_Pick[df2_ID %in% unique_ID1[id]]))
    if (nrec < 1L) {
        warning(nrec, " Pick values for ID:", unique_ID1[id], " in df2, ",
            "Drop was not replaced")
        # if no records in df2 for and ID from df1, retain Drop
    } else {
        pick <- df2_Pick[df2_ID %in% unique_ID1[id]]
        if (nrec > 1L) {
            warning(nrec, " Pick values for ID:", unique_ID1[id], 
                " in df2, ", "Drop was replaced with first element")
            pick <- pick[1]
        }
        # set the Drop value of each ID to be the corresponding Pick value
        df1_Drop[df1_ID == unique_ID1[id]] <- pick
    }
}
# Warning message:
# 0 Pick values for ID:100 in df2, Drop was not replaced 
df1_Drop
# [1] 1 4
```

It may make more sense to merge these columns instead, rather than manually collect records as above.

Comment: The data set are same and I have checked manually the assumption holds good when said that the df2 has all the data from df1.So looking for solution.If you can let me know is there any other way to create the loop to check would be great. Distribution of data based on weightage.

Comment: @ArkadeepPaulChoudhury I have proposed alternative code that should be more robust.

Comment: @CSJCambell Can you please rewrite the function I am still facing the issue.Seems missing something.Sorry for not able to make up from what you wanted to say.

`Cost_match<-match_cost(SingleValueDistribute = F,df1_ID = Net_Rev$`Man.ID`, 
                       df2_ID = Production_cost$Man.ID, 
                       df2_Pick = Production_cost$Man.Revenue, 
                       df1_Drop = Net_Rev$`Man.Revenue`, 
                       df1_Dist_by = Net_Rev$Revenue,dist = T,weighted = T)`

Comment: @ArkadeepPaulChoudhury please could you share a small dataset that shows the behaviour that is not working, and what output you expect to see. Thanks!